# How to trigger onPropertyChanged event on ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, maui

I have a custom class which inherits from ObservableCollection, where its Elemnent type raises OnPropertyChanged event but nothing happens

I have a following class

```cs
public class StudentsHandler: ObservableCollection<Student>{
        protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
            Trace.WriteLine("OnCollectionChanged!");
        }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
            Trace.WriteLine("OnPropertyChanged!");
        }
}
```

And the `Student` class looks like this

```cs
public class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public bool Present {
            get => _present;
            set
            {
                _present = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Present)));
                Trace.WriteLine("called!");
            }
        }
        private bool _present;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        ...
}
```

Changing the `Present` attribue of any student calls the setter, but `StudentsHandler`'s event methods don't get called. How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `ObservableCollection<Student>` will take care for triggering any events in order the UI to be updated. If any item added or deleted from the list, then the change will be automatically displayed to the page (see **Data binding and MVVM** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm?view=net-maui-8.0)

Still, you have to slightly modify the model to inform the MVVM that a potential change to any of the properties of the specific item will trigger an event. For example, if something changes on item that is already loaded to your ObservableCollection the `[ObservableProperty]` annotation will trigger the event again and the UI will be refreshed instantly.

```
public partial class StudentModel :ObservableObject
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ObservableProperty]
    string name;

}
```

The observable property is creating the below code. You can use this code to control what happens.

```
public string? Name
{
    get => name;
    set => SetProperty(ref name, value);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's not that I want to Update the UI - that already happens. I want to be able to control when that event occurs because I want to do more things with the collection at that time

Comment: So you can replace observable property with the code above. Check the updated answer. I assume that you want to handle the event of changing a single value of an item.

Comment: I've tried that already before (probably should have mentioned it) but to no avail. The two overwritten methods, which I posted above still refuse to report anything

Comment: Make sure that your model inherits ObservableObject

Comment: I've double checked and it does. I'm pretty sure that SetProperty method wouldn't be available without it

Comment: The student model in your question inherits INotifyPropertyChanged. Have you changed that?

Comment: I've tested it both with INotifyPropertyChanged and ObservableObject. Both don't work

Comment: Please share the code that is intended to trigger the event.

Comment: So, somewhere in your code you are modifying the ObservableCollection and change the Present attribute for a single item. In that specific point you can raise an event to do more things with the collection. May be is worth trying.